# Make my php server a symfony server

Tags: php, symfony, server, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to make my php server a Symfony server.
I've installed Symfony and I've created a project in /var/www/project_name
If i make `server:run my_local_ip:8000` the server run correctly and I can reach it also from a computer on another net with: `http://public_ip:8000`, instead, if I write `http://public_ip` it goes on my index.php.
Well, now, I'ld like that if I write `http://public_ip` it goes on `http://public_ip:8000` or atleast if could make Symfony run on port 80 or make Symfony run on php built-in server.
I've tried to create a virtual host, I've created this file:
**project_name.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName project_name
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
      RewriteRule .* - [F]
    </IfModule>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project_name
    <Directory /var/www/project_name>
      Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But it doesn't work and if I write `http://public_ip` it runs always my index.php.
Can you give me an help?

---

**Completed Solution - Thanks to @Alberto Fecchi answer:**

1. Edit 00-default.conf
2. Paste what you found on Alberto Fecchi's answer and also add this

> ```
> #IT NEEDS "<" BEFORE TAG
> Directory /var/www/tcgfiga/web/bundles>
>    IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>      RewriteEngine Off
>   </IfModule>
> /Directory>
> ```

3. Then make "sudo service apache2 restart". Sometimes it is necessary, sometimes not
4. Go into folder "/var/www/project/web/" and search ".htaccess" file
5. You should delete it, but if so your application doesn't run and you see and page with the content of the folder, recreate it and open it. You have to search

> ```
> <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
>   <IfModule mod_alias.c>
>     # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
>     # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
>     # and the generated links can still be used.
>     RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
>     # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
>   </IfModule>
> </IfModule>
> ```

6. Comment the line `RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/`

Now it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName project_name
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
      RewriteRule .* - [F]
    </IfModule>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project_name/web
    <Directory /var/www/project_name/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Enable it with `sudo a2ensite project_name` and restart with `sudo service apache2 restart` (commands could be different on various OS).

Now you can visit http://public_ip to see your "production" application.

Comment: it doesn't work. If I write "http://public_ip" it goes on "http://public_ip/app.php" and it said that the page doesn't work.

Comment: What happens on http://public_ip/app_dev.php? P.s. be sure that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: It says that I've not permission to look at it, cause I'm not on localhost!

Comment: However mod_rewrite is enabled!

Comment: This means that the virtualhost is working. Go to http://localhost/app_dev.php (if you can) and fix errors, OR temporary edit app_dev.php to accepts connections not only from localhost. This way, you can see what's happening in an easy way, make your fixes and get app.php to work. Also, you can make it without edit app_dev.php, just looking at var/logs/prod.log and see errors. Now it's a symfony problem, virtualhost is working

Comment: Woooo now it works. Do u know how I can erase "app.php" from browser?? Thank you!!

Comment: If mod rewrite is enabled it should already work without app.php. does .htaccess file exista in "web" folder?

Comment: Yes it exists in web folder